# Refer to symbol in another package not known at compile time in common-lisp

Tags: common-lisp

Is there a way to easily refer symbols in another other package without knowing it in advace ?

Let's say that I have a function like the following in a package names MY-PACKAGE

```
(defun foo-bar (foo bar)
  `((,foo . foo)
    (,bar . bar)))
```

If I call the above from the same package I'll get something like the following:

```
MY-PACKAGE> (foo-bar 1 2)
((FOO . 1) (BAR . 2))
```

If I call it from some other package, let's say CL-USER, the symbol returned refer to the package MY-PACKAGE:

```
CL-USER> (my-package:foo-bar 1 2)
((MY-PACKAGE:FOO . 1) (MY-PACKAGE:BAR . 2))
```

Sometimes, expecially when writing macros, I'd like to have the function return symbol interned in the package from which the function has been called (in this case CL-USER).
The only way I have been able to do this is by rewriting *foo-bar* as follows

```
(defun foo-bar (foo bar)
  `((,(intern "FOO" *package*) . ,foo)
    (,(intern "BAR" *package*) . ,bar)))
```

This gets ugly very soon, expecially when the symbols are given as parameters.
Is there any better way to handle this ?

Answer (score 1):

Functions are not called from a package. Packages are only used by the reader and by symbol creating functions like INTERN. At call time the symbols of a function are already interned in the package where the source code was originally read. For the function itself is does not matter how you get it's symbol name and call it.

If you want to create symbols in different packages based on, say, the value of the variable *package*, then you have to say so. INTERN is the way to create new symbols and the package is a parameter. It is also possible to create symbols without interning them in a package.

If the package for the symbol does not matter, then one might want to use uninterned symbols or, typically, keyword symbols. Keyword symbols are interned in the package keyword and evaluate to themselves.

Comment: Another option when symbol packages don't matter is to use STRING= as the test.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Rainer. I know that I can use INTERN, but I was wondering if it's the only choice, or if it can be done in a way different than mine. I'm not sure I can use uninterned symbols, because in some cases I need to compare their value. I could use keyword symbols or simply export the symbols I need, but it's not really what I want. I'm looking for something along the lines of the `loop` macro, where I can write e.g. `(cl:loop for x upto 10 collect x)` without having to use `:for` or `cl:for`

Comment: @Marco Righele: you can do simply replacement of the symbols. The macro gets an expression with symbols internal in some package. It then can walk over this expression in some way and replace specific internal symbols with symbols from a standard package. Usually the design of the LOOP macro that leads to symbols created in these packages is not seen as the best idea.

Answer (score 1):

Using `INTERN` with `*package*` is fine *if* you really intend to intern the key symbol of the association list in a different package depending on the context. However, note that `*package*` may not be bound to the package of the call unless you bind it explicitly. You can resolve that by **defining a macro instead of a function and use the `*package*` binding at macro expansion time.**

If the symbols are given as parameters to the function call, they are likely already interned in the package of the function call. Hence there is no need to use `INTERN`.

In case you are open to alternative approaches, Rainer's answer provides good suggestions such as using keyword symbols like `:foo` and `:bar` instead.

Comment: Hi Terje. Thanks for the explanation. The function is already part of a macro, so it shouldn't be a problem. The symbols are (possibly) already interned, but I don't know any other way to say "the symbol `foo` in the package `X`" (with X not know before the call).

Comment: `FIND-SYMBOL name &optional package` searches for the symbol named by name in package and returns the symbol if it is found. Both `name` and `package` can be strings not known before the call.